# Is it possible to stress test during test automating with selenium

Tags: selenium, stress-testing

I am new to selenium and stress testing.
By using selenium grid, we can somehow use selenium for stress testing but
is it possible to stress test during test automating with selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium is not a very good option for stress testing, mainly because you need too many machines to get to any reasonable load.

Using Selenium *while* running stress test is actually a good idea - you can get a better understanding of how your system behaves under load, but you'll need to drive the load from an external load testing product.